# How do I add this .tablink class to my in-content links to link between tabs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

The following code creates 3 bootstrap tabs.  The JavaScript code is supposed to load the pane for the tab that is clicked on.  The instructions were to "Use a .tablink class on your in-content links to link between tabs."  I am a newbee to JS. Where do I add the tablink class to get this Javascript code to work?

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs-tablink" id="prodTabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_basic">Basic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_images" data-url="?action=images">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_videos" data-url="?action=videos">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_basic" class="tab-pane active"> Basic content</div>
        <div id="tab_images" class="tab-pane active"> Images content</div>
        <div id="tab_videos" class="tab-pane active"> Videos content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tabs').on('click', '.tablink,#prodTabs a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        alert(url);
        if (typeof url !== "undefined") {
            var pane = $(this), href = this.hash;

            // ajax load from data-url
            $(href).load(url, function (result) {
                pane.tab('show');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).tab('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it's not clear what your goal is? try to break it down into pieces so that others can get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and effort, I found that the load order of the files (bootstrap and jquery) was the culprit. If these are wrong or duplicate loads, please let me know. The following order worked:

```
<!--JQueryUI-->
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Bootstrap-->
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

With the following code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
<li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
<li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
<div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">...Content a...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content b...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content c...</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    activaTab('aaa');
});

function activaTab(tab) {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top level navigation tabs are already wired up. You need to add some content to the tabs that include links to toggle over to the other tabs.

```
$('#tabs').on('click', '.tablink,#prodTabs a', function (e) {
```

I this line, the `#prodTabs a` links exist in your html but the `.tablink` links do not.

Try changing `<div id="tab_videos" class="tab-pane active"> Videos content</div>` to:

```
<div id="tab_videos" class="tab-pane active"> Videos content goes here.
There is a lot of it. It is about videos. If you want, you can switch to the 
<a href="#images_tab" class="tablink">Images Tab</a> from within this tab.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think this is close, but it will mean that I have to put the url link inside one tab to get to another tab.  The code executes when a tab is clicked (the alert() is triggered) and should take you directly to that tab without adding the link inside text in the tab. How would I do that?